# How can link BIT2 type to a variable?

Tags: twincat, codesys, st

In most `input cards` of Beckhoff, there are two variables, `Limit 1` and `limit 2`. They have a `BIT2` datatype, size of 0.2 bytes, which means they have two bits, as shown in the following figure for `Limit 1`:

```
Bit0: Value smaller/equal Limit 1
Bit1: Value bigger/equal Limit 1
```

[image]

so there are some questions:
what kind of datatype should I define to link this variable to it, and how can I access both of its bits.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `BIT` datatype in TwinCAT, but this is [only available within a struct or a function block](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/content/1033/tc3_plc_intro/2529442699.html?id=5627824830837717856).

You can for example define a STRUCT as follows (see also [InfoSys](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/content/1033/tc3_plc_intro/2529481355.html?id=5034243832068230001)):

```
TYPE Limits:
STRUCT
    SmallerThanOrEqualTo : BIT;
    LargerThanOrEqualTo : BIT;
END_STRUCT
END_TYPE
```

It should be possible to link an instance of this struct to the variable.

Note that using BIT access can be a [bit slower than using bit masks](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/content/1033/tc3_plc_intro/2529442699.html?id=5627824830837717856):

> However, bit access takes significantly longer. Therefore, you should only use the data type BIT if you want to define the data in a specified format.

[Toni Kucic](https://github.com/tkucic/codesys_code_execution_speedTests) did a speed comparison and found BIT access (13.5 ns) to be around a factor 5 slower than bit masks (2.8 ns). Full results:

[image: codesys timing of bit access versus dot access]

`BIT` datatypes do have the advantage that they [are much more memory efficient](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/content/1033/tc3_plc_intro/2529442699.html?id=5627824830837717856):

> A BIT element requires 1 bit of memory space, and you can use it to address individual bits of a structure or function block using its name. BIT elements, which are declared sequentially, are consolidated to bytes. This allows you to optimize memory usage compared to BOOL types, which each occupy at least 8 bits.

Answer (score 3):

I tried few things and I can't find anything, that you can link directly to `Limit1`. What you can do instead is to link a 16bit variable to `Status`, which `Limit1` and `Limit2` are parts of

[image]

`Limit1` will be available at bits 2 and 3, `Limit2` at bits 4 and 5. Just ignore the `Status_2EB64646` type, as it is not an actual type (Or maybe it is in some library?) and use any 16bit variable. `UINT` worked for me.

Comment: In general, bits can't be separately bound to in codesys. When you try to take the address of a BIT, for example, you instead get the address of the whole BYTE instead. Trying to define a REFERENCE TO BIT will error at compile time. Using a 16 bit type is probably the intended. If you want to simplify working with such data types, you could define a FUNCTION BLOCK that takes a reference/pointer to a UINT and abstracts access to those sub-values.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to link them to an `USINT` data type variable, `USINT` is an 8-bit data type but allows me to have directly the numeric value

[image]

In order to link them just need to change some filters during the variable linking procedure:
[image]

in the "Show Variable Types" section, select "All Types" and it will show every available variable from your plc project instance, after selecting the variable the following pop up will show up:

[image]

Confirm the standard values to avoid offset changes and then your variable will be linked!

i hope this approach helps someone.

Saludos Miguel